# How to add mapbox api in style specfication?

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I have setup mapbox like below:

```
var oMap = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: "map",
  style: "assets/mystyle.json",
  maxZoom: 18,
  minZoom: 7,
});
```

How to use following mapbox api in my styles specfication(mystyle.json)

```
mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11
mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10
mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v10
mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9
```

mystyle.json:

```
{
    "name": "Test App",
    "version": 8,
    "center": [
        54.515868,
        23.741252
    ],
    "zoom": 8,
    "sources": {
        "GoogleSatelliteMap": {
            "type": "raster",
            "tiles": [
                "https://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&hl=en&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}"
            ],
            "tileSize": 256
        }
    },
    "layers": [
        {
            "id": "GoogleSatelliteMap",
            "type": "raster",
            "source": "GoogleSatelliteMap",
            "layout": {
                "visibility": "none"
            },
            "paint": {
                "raster-opacity": 1
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

style specification:
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally clear what you're asking, but you can't embed one style within another one like that.

You could load the Mapbox style then add some additional layers on top.

Comment: I have setup my custom style and now i want to add mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9 in ?

Comment: That doesn't clarify anything.

Comment: then how to explain? I want to add "mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9" in my custome style json. that's it